# iOS - Share internet connection notification displacing view

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uinavigationbar, pixel

I don't know if it occurs too with iOS 6, but in iOS 7 when a mobile that has "sharing internet connection" option enabled, and is connected via usb with my computer, appears a kind of extra status bar that notifies this.

When it happens, the view under navigation bar moves down automatically 20 pixels to fit this notification bar.
So far there's no problem, because my view is shown correctly.
But in a concrete view, I've because the app navigation two navigation bars, one of them hidden (hidden but still existing and working).

So the system detects that there are two navigation bars, moves down my general view 20 pixels (that's ok to fit the bar), and then moves down the second view that is inside the first one, which has the hidden navigation bar. So at last you see the view 20 pixels under the navigation, separated by 20 pixels of nothing.

Is there any way to avoid this second automatic moving down?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prevent the status bar from moving your navigation bar (bars? it's unclear what you're saying on that point) as a result of internet connection sharing or a phone call. You might be able to hide the status bar and get rid of that effect, but Apple will almost certainly [reject your app for hiding the status bar unnecessarily](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Bars.html).

Comment: Well, with "bars" I mean the extended part that appears to notify the "internet connection sharing". 
I wouldn't hide the notification, I would like to avoid that my view gets moved down 20 pixels, being shown separated from navigation bar.

Comment: The 'bars' question I had was referring to your multiple navigation bars bit.